Getting net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) at http://localhost:5173/@vite/client in vite project
I have set up a Vite project for vuejs, following the quick start guide to learn the workflow of application development. However, upon launching the app on chrome (or any other browser for that matter), I get a blank page.
Checking the network tab, I find that a request to http://localhost:5173/@vite/client was being made by this dynamically injected Script tag <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>, which throws a 404-Not Found error.

NOTE: Out of curiosity, I tried setting up a react project with Vite on the same machine, and frustratingly enough, I got the same exact error.
Machine Details:

Windows 11 Enterprise Version 23H2
OS build - 22631.3880
Processor - 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1345U   1.60 GHz
System type - 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Node Version - 18.17.1 (managed by nvm-windows, have also tried a direct installation of node; same result)
NPM version - 9.6.7

I found a related question here, but the answer wasn't quite clear and didn't help much. Any Help would be highly appreciated as I am quite literally stuck with the project set-up stage itself.

After quite a bit of guessing what might be wrong, I was able to figure out the issue.
The parent folder name, where the project was set up in my PC, has a $ in the name. Once I renamed the folder to have non-special characters the project worked, I tried the same thing with the react project and it worked fine too.
Of course the solution may be specific to windows; but it works, so I guess we learned that development environments should not be placed in a path containing such special characters...

Glad you found a solution. They claim to have fixed this some time back in this PR but it could have recurred...
